# In typescript, how can I inherit from an external JS library using a declaration file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to write a .d.ts file for an external library (https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/).

I can map functions/objects but I don't see how to map the "inherit from objects defined in the JS library" logic (example: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/2.1/nodejs-driver/reference/addressResolution.html)

I didn't found anything related to this, any idea how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the library as well as in the definition the library you are trying to inherit from would need to be a class or constructor (in js) or a class, constructor or Interface in TypeScript.

This is actually a very common scenario when using TypeScript with React:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
```

Looking at the API for the node-casandra driver it looks like you should be able to this.

This is a naive example:

```
// cassandra-driver.d.ts
declare module "cassandra-driver" { 
    export class Client {}
}
```

Then:

```
import {Client} from 'cassandra-driver';

class Foo extends Client {

}
```

I would suggest [reading up](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html) on creating d.ts definitions. Create your definition as an external module -- not an ambient definition.

Then you should share your typing with the [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) or [DefinatlyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) or both projects.